# Gap between HeaderView and CollectionView

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a strange bug where there is a big gap between my collection view and my header view (a `UICollectionReusableView`). It looks like this:

[image]

Where the highlighted bit in blue is the header.

On the next image I have highlighted the UICollectionView:

[image]

One would think that this is to do with `sectionInset`'s, but that doesn't seem to be the case from my testing. All insets are 0. If I remove the header (or set the size in `heightForHeaderInSection` to 0) the problem goes away.

I am using the [CHTCollectionViewWaterFallLayout library](https://github.com/chiahsien/CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout).

My code is as follows:

```
func viewDidLoad() {
  ...
  collectionView.register(GridHeaderView.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: CHTCollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "albumInfoHeader")
  ...
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                      viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    let element = CHTCollectionElementKindSectionHeader
    
    switch kind {
    case CHTCollectionElementKindSectionHeader:
      let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: element,
                                                                       withReuseIdentifier: "albumInfoHeader", for: indexPath) as! GridHeaderView
      return headerView
    default:
      break
    }
    return UICollectionReusableView()
  }

func colletionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                     heightForHeaderInSection section: NSInteger) -> CGFloat {
    switch section {
    case 0:
      return 49
    default:
      return 0
    }    
  }
```

**UPDATE**

I now believe this to be a bug in `CHTCollectionViewWaterFallLayout`, and have filed a [bug](https://github.com/chiahsien/CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout/issues/161)

Comment: Are the next cells right next to each other or they also have the same huge space? Is distance from last cell to footer or end of collection view also that big?

Comment: @johnyu the cells are spaced normally, i.e. no huge space between them. There is no spacing like this at the footer

Comment: What's your layout's headerReferenceSize?

Comment: @johnyu I'm guessing you are not referring to the value I set in the above code? How do I inspect that?

Comment: I'm not setting a headerReferenceSize as the CHTCollectionLayout doesn't support that, it conforms to the heightForHeaderInSection

Comment: Hooray for 3rd party libraries. They promise so much...

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a storyboard, you can try selecting the checkbox for the UICollectionView "Adjust Scroll View Insets"

You can also try adding this into view controller's viewDidLoad method:

```
collectionView.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false;
```

Comment: I have tried disabling this in both storyboard and the viewcontroller to no avail.

Comment: are you using auto layout?

Comment: Yes, i am. I tried looking for weird constraints in the view debugger, but couldnt see much